# Blue Prism Active Accessibility error

Tags: blueprism, rpa

Internal: Failed to perform step 1 in navigate stage 'password aa mode'on page 'password-aa mode'-command send keys gave invalid result.

i'm unable to get the solution for the above error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwAlT.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are working with browser based application , so that HTML mode used for spy element and AA/Win32/Region Mode used for Window Application.

Option 1- First Spy password textbox via HTML mode in application modular & later use write stage to provide value to textbox

Option 2- In case Write stage will not work then you would move to GSK/GSKE text input methods and use navigate stage .

Regards
Vimal

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a Write stage instead, provided you have a model element spied for the password field (probably the same one you are trying to use with the Navigate stage +sendkey + text data item containing the password). Also, remember you should use the root application model (the one at the top of the list) with sendkeys if you insist on using the Navigate stage instead of a write.

Comment: I tried using write stage but it was not successful so I've used active accessibility mode for identifying elements and was successful to some extent in enabling  the login button which was disabled when html mode was used instead of AA mode.

Comment: Why aren't you using .html mode for this anyway? Try spying the password box as a html Element, then use a Navigate stage using that element to "point to the box" with an action "Double Click Centre" and then finally use a Write stage using the same element and your data item with the password. Also when spying in html mode remember to capture a bit high &/or wide as it probably won't  match the box exactly (like the AA mode), but should be alright for this.